# How to keep two colors circles together

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

The goal of this little program I am working on is to draw a red circle while radiobutton1 is checked, and draw a black circle while radiobutton2 is checked.

Below is my code, the problem with this code is when radiobutton1 is checked, it does draw red circles, but then if I click radiobutton2, then all the red circles will turn black. Then if check radiobutton1 again, the all the dots will turn red again.

How do I keep both color circles on the panel?

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

Graphics g;
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   points.Add(e.Location);
   panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        while (count < points.Count())
        {
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, points[count].X, points[count].Y, 10, 10);
            count++;
        }
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        while (count < points.Count())
        {
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, points[count].X, points[count].Y, 10, 10);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intent correctly, you need to keep two lists of points, one for each color.  Then, when you click somewhere, put the clicked point in the appropriate list (red or black).  Then, in your `Paint` event handler, replace the conditional code with two loops, one through each list of points (drawing the points from the red list in red and the points from the black list in black).

Code:

```
List<Point> redPoints = new List<Point>();
List<Point> blackPoints = new List<Point>();

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
        redPoints.Add(e.Location);
    else
        blackPoints.Add(e.Location);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    foreach (Point p in redPoints)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, p.X, p.Y, 10, 10);
    }
    foreach (Point p in blackPoints)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, p.X, p.Y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Note: if your circles overlap one another and you care about maintaining the layering order (first-clicked circles drawing first), then @Blorgbeard's solution is better because it keeps all the circles in the same list, thus maintaining the original layering.  Feel free to switch the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, @adv12, I am wondering, is it possible to have a background color that surrounds the red circle? And the background is also a circle, so the red circle is inside of the background circle, how should I approach this?

Comment: Sure, just draw two filled circles: first a black one, and then a smaller red one.  You'll have to decide how many pixels wider you want the background circle to be and offset/size the foreground circle accordingly.

Comment: thank you. Here is what I wrote, but then these two circles does not have a same center, how can I solve this?                  g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, p.X, p.Y, 30, 30);
g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, p.X, p.Y, 10, 10);

Comment: The circles are drawn within the rectangles you specify in the `FillEllipse` call.  You're specifying rectangles that start at (p.X, p.Y), one of which has a size of 10 and the other of which has a size of 30.  That's what I meant by "offset/size the foreground circle accordingly."  You can do the math.

Answer (score 3):

The way graphics works in Windows Forms is, the Paint method redraws the entire panel.

You are already drawing every point every time the paint method executes: this is correct.

But you have no way of remembering which point is supposed to be which color, so all you have to go on when you do the painting is the current values of the radiobuttons. You need some way of recording the current color when you add a circle.

One way to do this would be to define a Circle class which stores the location *and* color of a circle:

```
class Circle
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

Then instead of `points` being a `List<Point>`, it can be a `List<Circle>`, and when you see a mouse click, you can add a new `Circle` instead of a `Point`:

```
var circle = new Circle()
{
    Location = e.Location,
    Fill = radioButton1.Checked ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black
};
points.Add(circle);
```

And when you do the painting, you can check each circle's color as you draw them - all you have to do is this:

```
foreach (var circle in points)
{
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(circle.Fill, circle.Location.X, circle.Location.Y, 10, 10);
}
```

Note that you do not need a member level `Graphics g` - and it's a bad idea to keep a `Graphics` object after the `Paint` method has finished. It will not necessarily still be valid later. Always just use `e.Graphics`.

I also replaced your `while` loop with a simpler `foreach`.